# Display own post only and all posts for admin in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to display all posts which are added to admin and only own posts to the logged user.

This is what I've trying in my controller

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $items = Item::where('author_id', Auth::user()->id)->orderBy('id','DESC')->with('author')->paginate(5);
    return view('items.index',compact('items'))
        ->with('i', ($request->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
}
```

In the models I have this relations. 
Item model:

```
public function author()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

User model

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Item::class, 'author_id');
}
```

How can I make this if admin is logged to be able to see all posts? I'm using Entrust ACL and can't understand now how to change the query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Just check role and set condition. no need to write same query twice.

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $query = Item::orderBy('id','DESC')->with('author');
         if(!Auth::user()->hasRole('admin')){
              $query=$query->where('author_id', Auth::user()->id);
          }
        $items = $query->paginate(5);
        return view('items.index',compact('items'))
            ->with('i', ($request->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Working perfectly. First time dealing with ACL's and is still a bit confusing to me

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check if the current logged in user is an admin, and based on that run a query.

```
// If user has 'admin' role (or any other role set in Entrust) fetch all posts, else get all posts where author_id is the same as the logged user

if(Auth::user()->hasRole('admin')) {
    $items = Item::orderBy('id','DESC')->with('author')->paginate(5);
} else {
    $items = Item::where('author_id', Auth::user()->id)->orderBy('id','DESC')->with('author')->paginate(5);
}
```

`hasRole` returns `true` or `false` [[entrust docs]](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust#checking-for-roles--permissions)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Hm, this means I didn't made my roles as it must. If I have roles: `admin`, `author` and `user` how should be looking my routes groups? Currently I have 10 permissions which I attach to each role. I'm a bit confused in constructing this.

Comment: For example when I check `Entrust::hasRole('superadmin')` in logged in superadmin I see `1` which I assume is `true` but when I change to `Entrust::hasRole('author')` I see nothing.. I should see again `1`, right?